# PublishKafka_2_0 TimeoutException

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-nifi

I am using Apache Nifi 1.16.3. I am trying to publish some records through PublishKafka_2_0 processor but I am getting following error:

> PublishKafka_2_0 Failed to send StandardFlowFileRecord to Kafka:
> org.apache.kafka.common.errors.TimeoutException: Failed to update
> metadata after 10000 ms

I am using `PublishKafka_2_0 1.16.3`. I am trying to publish on kafka broker 3.2 as PLAINTEXT. Here are the configs:

[image: Setting]
[image: Scheduling]
[image: Properties]

I already tried using different PublishKafka versions and all not working. Also, I tried to increase max request size but that didn't help. I am just sending json message less than 1 MB.

Comment: Where is kafka running? Have you tested network connectivity from Nifi machines to the cluster? Also, turn off default SASL option if you're only using plaintext

Comment: @OneCricketeer
Yes network connectivity is there. And I can't turn off default SASL option. as plaintext uses active directory and for that GSSAPI needed.

Comment: In that case, you may need to configure either Kerberos or username/password or token auth options

Comment: @OneCricketeer I tried but not working

Comment: Without knowing what your kafka server.properties files look like, I don't think this is answerable... Are you able to use other Kafka producer clients like console producer? What configs do they use?